# Live Agent: Best Ways to Route by Account?

Tags: liveagent, omnichannel

I am trying to route chats in Live Agent by the account owner or account owner team. For ex., if an authenticated user chats in from customers website, I want that chat to route directly to the account owner, or to others that are apart of the account team, whoever has ability to answer. Currently we know the following:

1. we can pass account, contact and other details from the website into SF for known users that map to an account in SF.
2. We use account owner related list
3. We can assign users to queues.

what is the best way to do this, programmatically or declaratively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will likely change at some point, but we decided on the following direction:

1. Create as many queues as there are Account Teams. So let's say 100 queues in this case.
2. Map account team users under each queue (will be programmatically done).
3. Every queue is mapped to a button ID, so 100 of those too.
4. Setup logic to map queueID/buttonID to every account. This also rolls down to the contacts on the account.
5. Setup snapin deployment, map it to a default buttonID and queue.
6. Add pre-chat fields to prepop certain fields, including buttonID.
7. Add direct to button routing function in the snap in code snippet and route by buttonID

Answer (score 0):

If you have a small fixed number of account teams, you could create multiple chat buttons - one for each team and then show the correct button based on the account.

There is also a feature for [direct to agent routing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_direct_to_agent_code_sample.htm). I've used it to route to a single agent with a failover to a queue. You could use this to route the chat to the account owner.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a way to setup separate logic to route an authenticated user and data that we collect from their session (accountID, first name, last name, email, etc) to a specific queue mapped to their account?

Comment: Each queue needs to be associated to a separate chat button. You would need to query the account to determine the queue/chat button id to present the correct chat button to the user.

Comment: Makes sense. Are you aware of which API to use to perform this action? Deployment API? I am hoping to utilize snap ins. I think if I have some logic in place on tbe Salesforce side, I can make a call against account ID on the website, into SF,  to grab the associated button/queue etc. its just not clear to me which API and what function at this point

Comment: To query, you'd need to use either the SOAP or REST API. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm